# IsoStorageManager

Tags: c#, json, async-await, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

A manager for a speedy async saving objects to isolated storage, using serialization from Newtonsoft.Json. A project to play with is [here](https://isostoragemanager.codeplex.com/).

```
public static async Task<T> ReadJsonEx<T>(String filepath)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
            return default(T);

        return await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, store))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                return await jr.ReadJsonAsyncTask<T>();
        });
    }

    public static async Task<bool> WriteJsonEx<T>(String filepath, T content)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
            return false;

        return await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, store))
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                await jw.WriteJsonAsyncTask(content);

            return true;
        });
    }
```

Where extensions are

```
private static readonly JsonSerializer JsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore };

    public static async Task<bool> WriteJsonAsyncTask<T>(this JsonTextWriter writer, T content)
    {
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        return await TaskEx.Run(() =>
        {
            try { JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, content); }
            catch (Exception) { return false; }
            return true;
        });
    }

    public static async Task<T> ReadJsonAsyncTask<T>(this JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        return await TaskEx.Run(() => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(reader));
    }
```

I'm just wondering if this code is secure and if it can be used in the real app.
Is the current approach safe enough?

Comment: These edits can probably earn you some rep if you word them into an answer / "selfie" review ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug fair enough :) Thanks, would move them there.

Comment: Also, please don't edit the code in the question. I've rolled back Rev 14 → 13.

Comment: @200_success it was almost the same, just with extra CreateFolderIfNecessary() call. Though, i got your point: code samples should stay original.

Answer (score 3):

This is very neat. Just a few code formatting nitpicks:

> ```
>     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
>         return default(T);
>
>     return await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
>     {
>         using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
>         using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, store))
>         using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
>         using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
>             return await jr.ReadJsonAsyncTask<T>();
>     });
> ```

Call me over-zealous, I think it would be best to specify the scopes with curly braces - I like the stacked `using` blocks though, so like this:

```
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    return await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, store))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            return await jr.ReadJsonAsyncTask<T>();
        }
    });
```

And here too:

> ```
> public static async Task<bool> WriteJsonAsyncTask<T>(this JsonTextWriter writer, T content)
> {
>     writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
>     return await TaskEx.Run(() =>
>     {
>         try { JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, content); }
>         catch (Exception) { return false; }
>         return true;
>     });
> }
> ```

I find code reads better going down than going across:

```
public static async Task<bool> WriteJsonAsyncTask<T>(this JsonTextWriter writer, T content)
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    return await TaskEx.Run(() =>
    {
        try 
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, content);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
            return false; 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As a matter of style, I'd also put the `return true;` within the `catch` block to show the entire "happy path".

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer good point - I put it in the `try` block though ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for a review. However, it is indeed only a matter of style :)

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Meh, the downside of reviewing nice code ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug well.. agree :)

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Thanks for idea, i'll use it either.

Answer (score 3):

Talking about code stability, I had found several issues so far:

1. I tried to call `WriteJsonEx()` from the `Application_Deactivated()` to save some data - sometimes it works, but several times it failed to finish writing before app deactivates.

   I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936279/cant-save-data-to-storagefile-while-app-is-being-deactivated?rq=1). In a short: calling async during app deactivation is a bad idea. Sync calls should be used instead (app has several seconds to store data, so sync calls should works fine).
2. No folder autocreation

   Just call `DirectoryExists()` and `CreateDirectory()` if needed. Will update sample in a while.
3. Is it thread-safe?

   Probably adding `lock()` would help, should test it deeper.

EDIT: I'm doing some crash-tests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582262/async-reader-writer-locker). Will publish the results in this thread either.